# Find the minimum value of the function $f(x)=\frac{x^p}{p}+\frac{x^{-q}}{q}$,where $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1$ and $p>1$

Tags: calculus, inequality, maxima-minima, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, holder-inequality

I know that this can be solved with calculus by differentiating w.r.t. x and equating it to zero.
So, $f'(x)=(x^{p+q}-1)/x^{q+1}$ and on solving we find that $f(x)$is minimum at $x=1$.

But, I was wondering if there was a way of solving this problem by using the Holder's inequality as the conditions given in the question seem very similar to the conditions of the holder's inequality. Any other way of solving the problem without the use of calculus is most welcome. Thanks!

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, $f'(x) = x^{p-1} - x^{q-1}$

Comment: @TomCollinge Yea sorry i fixed it

Comment: Not fixed yet.... $-1/x^{q+1} = x^{-q-1}$

Comment: @TomCollinge There was a typo in the question (T_T)

Comment: What range of $x$ is applicable ? Clearly $x=0$ would be a problem with this corrected expression. Presumably $x > 0$.

Comment: It is an immediate application of [Young's inequality for products](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young%27s_inequality_for_products)

Comment: @MartinR Maybe if it were $x^{+q}$ not $x^{-q}$ ?

Comment: @TomCollinge Well, there's no range in the question so I guess x>0 is the range

Comment: @TomCollinge: Young's inequality with $a=x$ and $b=1/x$ ...

Comment: @MartinR Ah.......

Comment: @MartinR Wow that was surprisingly easy.. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $x > 0$ (otherwise the terms $x^p$ and $x^{-q}$ are not well-defined) we can apply [Young's inequality for products](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young%27s_inequality_for_products):

$$
f(x) =\frac{x^p}{p}+\frac{(1/x)^{q}}{q} \ge x \frac 1x = 1 \, .
$$
Equality holds if $x^p = (1/x)^q$, that is for $x=1$.